# NSTimer with SwiftLoading

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am using SwiftLoading:

https://www.miniassets.com/news/1-create-loading-with-activity-indicator-in-swift-2-and-xcode-7.html

To hide it, I use an NSTimer:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func update()
{
    SwiftLoading().hideLoading()
}
```

The Function "update()" is fired after 4 Seconds, and also the function hideLoading() is fired, but the Loading View stays on the screen.

Does anyone know, why this happens?

Comment: are you sure `update` is fired ?. did you put breakpoint or checked with logs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SwiftLoading().hideLoading()
```

This line creates a *new* `SwiftLoading`, and then hides that one instead of the existing one.

When you first create your `SwiftLoading`, you should assign it to an instance variable so you can hide it later:

```
let loading = SwiftLoading()    //in your class, as an instance variable
```

To start the loading object:

```
loading.showLoading()
```

To hide the loading object:

```
loading.hideLoading()
```

Comment: Since it is firing from a timer, it will probably need dispatch_async because it is not on the main thread;.

Comment: @ryantxr `NSTimer`s use the run loop, so it will be called on the main thread.  You're probably thinking about `dispatch_after`.

Comment: @ NobodyNada: Wow that fixed my problem! No it fires correctly, thank you very much!